# Inner Joining the same table multiple times

Tags: sql, inner-join

So I have received this error: #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'Purchase'

I am trying to do the following:

```
    SELECT Blank.BlankTypeCode
          ,Blank.BlankCode
          ,Payment.Amount
          ,Payment.Type
          ,Purchase.PurchaseDate
          ,Payment.DatePaid
FROM Blank
INNER JOIN Ticket
ON Blank.BlankCode = Ticket.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN MCO_Blank
ON Blank.BlankCode = MCO_Blank.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN Purchase
ON  Ticket.PurchaseID = Purchase.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Purchase
ON MCO_Blank.PurchaseID = Purchase.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment
ON Ticket.PurchaseID = Payment.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment
ON MCO_Blank.PurchaseID = Payment.PurchaseID
WHERE Payment.Status = "Paid";
```

Blank Table consists of:

```
BlankCode,
IssueDate,
Status,
UserID, 
BlankTypeCode
```

Payment Table consists of:

```
Type,
Amount,
Status,
DueDate,
PurchaseID,
CurrencyRateDate
```

Purchase Table consists of:

```
PurchaseID,
CustomerID,
PurchaseDate,
TotalFare,
TaxAmount,
CurrencyType,
Purchasecol
```

Ticket Table consists of:

```
Price,
PurchaseID,
Blank_BlankCode,
Blank_BlankTypeCode,
TicketType,
Airline_Name
```

MCO_Blank Table consists of:

```
Service,
Cost,
Description,
Purchase_PurchaseID,
Blank_BlankCode,
Blank_BlankTypeCode
```

I am unsure of how I can make this work.

Comment: Very good question; for example:  could be used if different fields are needed, each possibly having a different 'join ID'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use table aliases.  You have mentioned the same table more than once in the `from` clause.  The query is something like this:

```
SELECT b.BlankTypeCode, b.BlankCode, pa1.Amount, pa1.Type, p1.PurchaseDate, pa2.DatePaid
FROM Blank b
INNER JOIN Ticket t
ON b.BlankCode = t.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN MCO_Blank mb
ON b.BlankCode = mb.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN Purchase p1
ON  t.PurchaseID = p1.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Purchase p2
ON mb.PurchaseID = p2.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment pa1
ON t.PurchaseID = pa1.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment pa2
ON mc.PurchaseID = pa2.PurchaseID
WHERE pa1.Status = "Paid";
```

I had to make a guess at which payment and purchase is intended for the aliases.  These may not be correct in the `from` and `where` clauses.

Comment: The thing is I am also using ON with columns that I won't be viewing in the result set and so I am unsure as to what the aliases would be for this.

Comment: @JP24 . . . I think the aliases in the `on` clauses are correct.  They are easier to figure out, because they should refer to the "nearest" table reference.

Comment: I tried putting this on but I recieved an error -#1054 - Unknown column 'p2.DatePaid' in 'field list'

Comment: @JP24: Since none of your tables has a `DatePaid` column, you've got a problem with the select-list in your original query.  The date column there appears to be `PurchaseDate`.

Answer (score 3):

You need a different alias for the table each time you use it.

```
SELECT B.BlankTypeCode, B.BlankCode, A1.Amount, A1.Type, P1.PurchaseDate, P1.DatePaid
  FROM Blank AS B
  JOIN Ticket    AS T  ON B.BlankCode = T.Blank_BlankCode
  JOIN MCO_Blank AS M  ON B.BlankCode = M.Blank_BlankCode
  JOIN Purchase  AS P1 ON T.PurchaseID = P1.PurchaseID
  JOIN Purchase  AS P2 ON M.PurchaseID = P2.PurchaseID
  JOIN Payment   AS A1 ON T.PurchaseID = A1.PurchaseID
  JOIN Payment   AS A2 ON M.PurchaseID = A2.PurchaseID
 WHERE A1.Status = "Paid"
   AND A2.Status = "Paid"
```

You'll need to sort out which versions of the Purchase and Payment tables the selected columns come from, and also what should be in the WHERE clause really.

Answer (score 3):

You can't join a table more than once using the same name, so either join it with an alias like `inner join purchase p1 on...`  or use both of the join predicates together like `inner join purchase ON first predicate AND second predicate`

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT bl.BlankTypeCode
          ,bl.BlankCode
          ,pymt.Amount
          ,pymt.Type
          ,purc.PurchaseDate
          ,pymt.DatePaid
FROM Blank bl 
INNER JOIN Ticket tk
ON bl.BlankCode = tk.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN MCO_Blank mco_bl
ON bl.BlankCode = mco_bl.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN Purchase purc
ON  tk.PurchaseID = purc.PurchaseID
AND mco_bl.PurchaseID = purc.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment pymt
ON tk.PurchaseID = pymt.PurchaseID
AND mco_bl.PurchaseID = pymt.PurchaseID
WHERE pymt.Status = "Paid";`

Answer (score 1):

```
INNER JOIN Purchase
ON MCO_Blank.PurchaseID = Purchase.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment                         --<-- 
ON Ticket.PurchaseID = Payment.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment                         --<--
ON MCO_Blank.PurchaseID = Payment.PurchaseID
WHERE Payment.Status = "Paid";
```

You have joined Payments table twice, If you do need to join it twice you need to Alias it , a different alias everytime you join this table.