# How can I display tablenames in resultheader of SQL Server 2008 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, resultset

I am analysing a large query with lots of joins on different tables that all get aliases in the joins. Some tables are joined twice with different aliases.

For example the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641296/894974):

```
SELECT *
FROM Blank b
INNER JOIN Ticket t ON b.BlankCode = t.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN MCO_Blank mb ON b.BlankCode = mb.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN Purchase p1 ON  t.PurchaseID = p1.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Purchase p2 ON mb.PurchaseID = p2.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment pa1 ON t.PurchaseID = pa1.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment pa2 ON mc.PurchaseID = pa2.PurchaseID
WHERE pa1.Status = "Paid";
```

I would like my results grid to display the table aliases in the columns. Is that in any way possible other than using an alias for each column in the `select`?

So my columnheader should look like this:

```
b.BlankTypeCode|b.BlankCode|pa1.Amount|pa1.Type|p1.PurchaseDate| pa2.DatePaid
```

instead of

```
BlankTypeCode|BlankCode|Amount|Type|PurchaseDate|DatePaid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to alias each column in the select query, but there is a slightly quicker way to do it. Place your mouse cursor before `b.BlankCode`, and then, *holding down the Alt key*, click and drag to select down to a few spaces after `pa2.DatePaid`.

Press `Ctrl + C`.

Now enter a few spaces after `b.BlankCode` (to ensure you are past the vertical column of the most stuck out bit, and press `Ctrl + V`

This is a quick way to create aliases for your columns, and you can type into multiple columns this way as well.

Comment: Along with displaying the query in the designer window, this worked like a treat!

Answer (score 3):

use This

```
SELECT b.BlankTypeCode AS [b.BlankTypeCode]
, b.BlankCode AS [b.BlankCode]
, pa1.Amount AS [pa1.Amount]
, pa1.Type AS [pa1.Type]
, p1.PurchaseDate AS [p1.PurchaseDate]
, pa2.DatePaid AS [pa2.DatePaid]

FROM Blank b
INNER JOIN Ticket t
ON b.BlankCode = t.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN MCO_Blank mb
ON b.BlankCode = mb.Blank_BlankCode
INNER JOIN Purchase p1
ON  t.PurchaseID = p1.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Purchase p2
ON mb.PurchaseID = p2.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment pa1
ON t.PurchaseID = pa1.PurchaseID
INNER JOIN Payment pa2
ON mc.PurchaseID = pa2.PurchaseID
WHERE pa1.Status = "Paid";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that would be a fine option if I had only 6 columns to display, but as I'm analysing the query and have over 20 columns. Maybe I should specify that I am using `select * from`

Comment: Sander, don't use `select *`, instead go to the table in the object explorer, expand the table, and drag the columns folder to the work window. This will fill all the column names out for you.

Comment: @RussAwesome that was an awesome suggestion! I realised there are more than one ways to write a query and displayed it in the query designer. There, ssms rewrote my query to replace the * with all the columns from all the joins. Now I can easilly mangle the columns into columns with aliasses.

Answer (score 1):

> *It is not recommended using blank spaces or Dot(.) or any other special charecters is column names*

but if you need so then you can change it like this :

change the code like this :

```
    SELECT 
b.BlankTypeCode as "b.BlankTypeCode"
    , b.BlankCode as "b.BlankCode "
    , pa1.Amount as "pa1.Amount"
    , pa1.Type as "pa1.Type"
    , p1.PurchaseDate as "p1.PurchaseDate"
    , pa2.DatePaid as "pa2.DatePaid"

    FROM Blank b
    INNER JOIN Ticket t
    ON b.BlankCode = t.Blank_BlankCode
    INNER JOIN MCO_Blank mb
    ON b.BlankCode = mb.Blank_BlankCode
    INNER JOIN Purchase p1
    ON  t.PurchaseID = p1.PurchaseID
    INNER JOIN Purchase p2
    ON mb.PurchaseID = p2.PurchaseID
    INNER JOIN Payment pa1
    ON t.PurchaseID = pa1.PurchaseID
    INNER JOIN Payment pa2
    ON mc.PurchaseID = pa2.PurchaseID
    WHERE pa1.Status = "Paid";
```